# How can I change the key value in an object when creating an array value while using the map function in React?

Tags: javascript, array-map

I have the data of the array object in a variable called hi[0].child.

```
hi[0].child = [
    {code: "food", name: "buger"},
    {code: "cloth", name: "outher"},
    {code: "fruit", name: "apple"},
]
```

What I want to do is create a variable called hello, change the key value of hi[0].child, and put it in the hello variable.

For example, the key value of code is changed to value and name is changed to label. The values ​​I want are as below.

```
expecter answer 

hello = [
    {label: "burger", value: "food"},
    {label: "outher", value: "cloth"},
    {label: "apple", value: "fruit"},

]
```

But when I use my code I get these errors.

Did not expect a type annotation here

so How can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
let hello = []


hi[0].child.map((v) => {
hello.push(label: v.name, value: v.code)
})
```

Comment: **Just a typo**. You're missing the braces that denote the parameter as an object... `hello.push({label: v.name, value: v.code})`

Comment: FYI this might be a little cleaner and actually uses `.map()` for what it's meant for... `const hello = hi[0].child.map(({ name, code }) => ({ label: name, value: code }))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed the curly brackets for the object, it should be `hello.push({ label: v.name, value: v.code })`.

Also, `map` is *not* the right method to be used here, use `forEach` instead *or* use the value returned from `map` (as shown below).

```js
const data = [
  { code: "food", name: "buger" },
  { code: "cloth", name: "outher" },
  { code: "fruit", name: "apple" },
];

const updatedData = data.map((v) => ({ label: v.code, value: v.name }));

console.log(updatedData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the code like this

```
let hello = []
hi[0].child.map((v) => {
  hello.push({label: v.name, value: v.code})
})
```

You need to pass object

Comment: `map` returns a modified array, so you should use the returned values instead of pushing to a new array or change the method to `forEach`. Also, `push` can be done on array declared as `const`.